# Unable to get Results of a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am newbie to SQL.
I have this query
[image]

I am not sure where i am doing it wrong.
Can you guys help me out?
thanks.

Comment: should be single quote

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Tried it but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three mistakes:

1. You need single quotes
2. MySql expects two-digit months
3. The `2015-09-30` end date includes an implicit midnight for the time component, which excludes most of the day

Put it all together you get this:

```
SELECT * FROM results WHERE played_on BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-10-01';
```

While I'm here, I prefer to avoid `BETWEEN` in favor of explicit bounds. There's always that chance someone codes a game for exactly midnight October 1:

```
SELECT * FROM results WHERE played_on >= '2015-09-01' AND played_on < '2015-10-01';
```

And you would have had this answer faster if I could have copy/pasted the query text from your post instead of having to re-type. Posting images of sample data or code instead of the text is considered very rude here.

Comment: Thanks Joel it Worked.

Comment: so Single Quotes works for Numeric ..? Why not use double Quotes here?

Comment: Date literals are not considered numerics. Double quotes are reserved by the ansi standard for column identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use [MySql Date Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) like MONTH() and YEAR() for this query :

```
SELECT * FROM results WHERE MONTH(played_on) = 9 AND YEAR(played_on) = 2015
```

I hope this answer can help you.

Comment: This will work, but it's not sargeable (doesn't work with indexes). The only slower way to do this is via string parsing.